# INDIRECT Function for Dependent Dropdown Lists

Tags: excel

I know how to make a dependent dropdown list but the issue that I'm facing and can't seem to get solved is the following.

I've created a table with product groups and to each product group I assigned individual products.

[image]

- A4:A6 I've called `Product`
- B4:B7 I've called `Fruit`
- C4:C7 I've    called `Wine`

[image: D4:D7 I've called <code>Sweets</code>]
[image]

When I do than a data validation (Cell B10) -> list -> =Product
I get a list of all the products (Fruit, Wine and Sweets)

In the cell below I do data validation (Cell B11) -> list -> =INDIRECT($B$10)

When I select for example fruit in cell B10, I get a list of all the Fruits in cell B11.

Now my question is:

Lets say that I want to replace Fruit with Fruit & Vegetables, see table below. Than it doesn't work anymore. I've tried everything but can't seem to figure it out. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: A screenshot can help the understanding.

Comment: Without any more information, I'd suggest using a named range without spaces...

Comment: @Vityata: Just added a screenshot. Is it clear now what I want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Name your title/range "Wine_and_Spirits"

Why?
Named ranges cannot use the "&" character.

A google search on illegal characters in excel names found this pretty quick:

> What characters are allowed? The first character of a name must be a letter, an underscore character (_), or a backslash ().
>   Remaining characters in the name can be letters, numbers, periods, and underscore characters

Comment: Yes, that I know. But how can I display the names as shown in my example and make it work?

Comment: Format cell--> custom--> "Wine & Spirits"
:)

Comment: I do not understand.  You can format your cell to show "Wine & Spirits" and then no matter what you will write in the cell, it will always display "Wine & Spirits".
You need to include the quotation marks.
Right click cell--> format cells--> custom--> "Wine & Spirits"

Comment: Pardon, this is incorrect.  This works only when a number is in the cell.  I'll give it another thought.

Comment: I do not think I can solve this one without some monkey business. For example, how about placing the illegal name in the top row and then not including this in your named range and hiding second row which would have the same title name as your dynamic range?.

Comment: Yes, more clear now.  But I still think we have the same problem, you can't name your range using the illegal character &.  Hence, you can't call that range into your list, because a range with this name is not possible.  My monkey suggestion is to add a new row below the title (new row nr4).  Add your legal name for the range there such as "Wine_and_Spirits" then name your ranges starting from line number 5.  After this, you hide row number 4 so only "Wine & Spirits" is visible, just not being used as a reference.  Look forward to seeing if someone has a non-monkey solution to this :)

Comment: your monkey solution doesn't work :( I can't believe that this isn't possible. There must be more people with this issue